# Posso usar o jQuery 2 no Emberjs 2.1?

Tags: javascript, jquery, emberjs

Gostaria de fazer um upgrade do jQuery 1.11.3 para o jQuery 2.1 dentro do Ember 2.1. Posso fazer esse upgrade sem grandes problemas?

Link para questão no [SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33543738/can-i-upgrade-jquery-2-in-ember-2-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É possível utilizar a nova versão do jQuery sem medo. Para isso basta entrar no arquivo `bower.json` e adicionar a versão deseja. Após isso rodar o `bower install` novamente.

É importante lembrar também que as versões mais novas do jQuery não dão suporte para navegadores antigos.